# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in react router when rendering components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to separate my route file from my App.js for code splitting and cleaner code (I think).

```html
//routes.js
  

  const routes = [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: () => import('../components/Home')
        },
        {
            path: '/about',
            component: () => import('../components/About')
        }
    ]

    export default routes;

//App.js
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';

import './App.css';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import routes from './router/routes';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <Switch>
            {routes.map((entry) => { return (<Route {...entry} />) })}
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

But it gives me an error

> ×
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

I'm trying to render the components from routes but it won't render though I don't get any error from vscode but in my browser it gives me error.

UPDATE:
I changed the code from

```
 {routes.data.map((entry) => { return (<Route {...entry} />) })}
    to 
{routes.map((entry) => { return (<Route {...entry} />) })}
```

and got new error

```
> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in component (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at App.js:30)
    in Switch (at App.js:29)
    in div (at App.js:19)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at App.js:18)
    in App (at src/index.js:9)
    in StrictMode (at src/index.js:8)
```

Comment: Can you try :  {routes.map((entry) => { return (<Route {...entry} />) })}

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `.map` on '`data`' which does not exist on your `routes` constant. Use `routes.map`

Answer (score 0):

You call `routes.data`, so Your object should look like this:

```
      const routes = [
       data:[
           {
               path: '/',
               component: () => import("./pages/roles/SystemRolesPage")
           },

       ]
    ]
```

with one another nested level - when U use
`{routes.map((entry) => { return (<Route {...entry} />) })}`

it should work